# Is there a way to slice a polygon using shapely?

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I have a geodataframe as follows:

Here is the layer:

[image]

```
# adjust the CRS
gdf= gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:26191'}) 

# compute the area in km2
gdf["area_km2"] = gdf['geometry'].area/ 10**6
```

I wonder if there is a systematic way to cut each polygon in four, five (or more) parts programmatically based on the area for example?

My aim to slice each polygon in a defined number of sub-polygons.

Is that possible?

Comment: I added some clarifications in the question. Hopefully that clarifies the question. The shape of the sub-polygon does not matter at the moment but it could at some point. I would like to find a flexible way to slice the polygon and do my research from there. Thank you

Comment: If you have access to qgis you can try this plugin https://github.com/jonnyhuck/RFCL-PolygonDivider or you can take a look at the source code. Another idea could be slice by a defined grid, create centroids and use voronoi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a square grid over each polygon, intersect it with the polygon, then cumulatively sum the split areas until the best split position is found, then dissolve into n parts.

Like this before the dissolve:
[image]

Seems to work pretty well. The areas deviate < 1 % from the optimal area and it doesnt take very long to process.

The splits are vertical because of how the grid is created. You can sort the grid if you want to split horizontally or otherwise.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import shapely

file = r"/home/bera/Drives/data1/gisdata/LMV/Topografi50/230721/4eb87709-ab27-4f49-9182-e20cd0872bc4/naturvard_sverige.gpkg"
df = gpd.read_file(filename=file, engine="pyogrio")
df["tempid"] = range(df.shape[0]) #Create a unique id per row, to groupby


n_parts = 5 #The number of parts you want to split each polygon into
result_frames = [] #A list to hold result dataframes
for counter, (temp_id, subframe) in enumerate(df.groupby("tempid"),1): #For each row/feature/polygon
    print(f"Splitting polygon {counter} / {df.shape[0]}") #Print progress
    
    #Create a grid geodataframe covering the feature/subframe
    gridsize=20 #The size of the square grid cell. Adjust. Smaller size should give more equal size parts, but will make execution time longer
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = subframe.geometry.total_bounds
    xcoords = np.arange(start=xmin, stop=xmax, step=gridsize)
    ycoords = np.arange(start=ymin, stop=ymax, step=gridsize)
    coordinates = np.array(np.meshgrid(xcoords, ycoords)).T.reshape(-1,2)
    squares = [shapely.Point(*c).buffer(distance=gridsize/2, cap_style=3) for c in coordinates]
    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={"gridid":range(len(squares))}, geometry=squares, crs=df.crs)
    
    #Intersect the subframe and grid To create a polygon split into small mostly square pieces
    intersection = gpd.overlay(df1=subframe, df2=grid, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)
    
    #Calculate cumulative area 
    intersection["cumsum"] = intersection.area.cumsum()
    
    #Calculate optimal area splits
    total_area = intersection.area.sum()
    part_area_goal = total_area/n_parts
    optimal_splits = [round(part_area_goal*n) for n in range(1, n_parts+1)] #A list where to split the intersection df.
    #For example [704934, 1409867, 2114801, 2819734, 3524668]
    #So the first part should consist of all polygons in intersection df up to the cumsum 704934
    # The next part from 704934-1409867 ...
    
    #Find the indices of the nearest cumulative areas
    split_at_index = []
    for part, split in enumerate(optimal_splits, 1):
        df_closest = intersection.iloc[(intersection['cumsum']-split).abs().argsort()[:1]] #https://www.statology.org/pandas-find-closest-value/
        split_at_index.append(df_closest.index[0])
        intersection.loc[df_closest.index[0], "part"]=part #Insert a part id at the optimal index
    
    intersection.part = intersection.part.bfill().ffill() #Fill in all nulls before and after the part ids
    dissolved = intersection.dissolve(by="part", as_index=False) #Dissolve by part id. 
    
    result_frames.append(dissolved)

result = gpd.pd.concat(result_frames)
result.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/split_data.gpkg", driver="GPKG")


Splitting polygon 1 / 5
Splitting polygon 2 / 5
Splitting polygon 3 / 5
Splitting polygon 4 / 5
Splitting polygon 5 / 5
```

[image]

Comment: Dear BERA. How did you define the `bbox=(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)`?. Does it have to be defined? when I read my gdf using your definition of `bbox` i get an empty dataframe.

Comment: I removed `bbox` from the read subset as you suggested but I am getting an error in the projection. `UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'area' are likely incorrect. Use GeoSeries.to_crs() to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation`. I checked the `crs` of the `grid` and the `subframe` and there are the same (`4326`).  When I plot the output I see that my polygons are not split

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well now. As you said, the split is vertical. My polygons were split vertically too. It seems so un-natural. Can we split both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: I am trying to augment the code with one horizontal split. Basically, i d like to keep the `n vertical` splits and add one horizontal split which would amount to `n*2` splits in total in one polygon. The piece of code you wrote is challenging me. Any chance you can explain please.  `squares = [shapely.Point(*c).buffer(distance=gridsize/2, cap_style=3) for c in coordinates]`